# VB.NET Click Handler Error

Tags: vb.net, events

I have the following code:

```
CType(epuc, PropSoftware.SimpleUIControls.GenericPaymentControl).clickEvent = New EventHandler(AddressOf BtnAccept_Click)
```

and the following handler

```
Public Sub BtnAccept_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
```

But when I click the button, I'm not getting any response...which means the click event is not being triggered.  Any idea why?

Comment: Whom on Earth calls a Click event "clickEvent"?  How did this compile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use AddHandler.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7taxzxka(v=vs.80).aspx#Y158

or WithEvents + Handles

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6k46st1y(v=VS.90).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Use Addhandler:

```
AddHandler CType(epuc, PropSoftware.SimpleUIControls.GenericPaymentControl).clickEvent, AddressOf BtnAccept_Click
```

Comment: Interestingly if I use what you wrote, I get the following compilation error: 'clickEvent' is not an event of 'PropSoftware.SimpleUIControls.GenericPaymentControl'.

Comment: Use intellisence to check what the events name is, maybe its just .Click?